# About the definition or algorithm of the "value" component in the output of solve.qp in quadprog, R

Tags: r, algorithm, optimization, quadprog

I am using `solve.QP` in `quadprog` package of R to solve the classical mean-variance optimization problem. In my understanding, the output component "value" means the variance of the optimized portfolio and many codes for the mean-variance optimization posted online also show that `sqrt(sol$value)` is the standard deviation of the optimized portfolio.

However, when I use `solve.QP` to solve a simple mean-variance optimization, `sol$value` provides me a negative value which is also different from the value calculated by using the portfolio variance function: `w%*%covariance%*%t(w)`. I was trying to search online for the definition or the algorithm for `sol$value` but unfortunately I could not find detailed description. The R Documentation for `quadprog` only states that "value" is "scalar, the value of the quadratic function at the solution".

So could anyone who is familiar with `solve.QP` could tell me the exact definition or algorithm of `sol$value`. And if my understanding about it is correct, namely the variance of the optimized portfolio, then what is the possible reason that `solve.QP` provides me negative values for `sol$value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`solve.QP` is a *general* solver for quadratic optimization problems. So you have to be aware of which quadratic problem you are actually solving. Since you are dealing with mean-variance portfolio optimization, your's is probably like

```
 wopt=argmax_w(t(w)%*%r-lambda*t(w)%*%C%*%w)
```

with `r`, `w`, `lambda` and `C` being the expected return, the portfolio weights, the risk aversion parameter and the covariance matrix, respectively. `wopt` is the optimal weights vector. `sol$value` will give you the value of your objective function at `wopt`.

Some other mean-variance formulations try to maximize `t(w)%*%r` with a constraint on the risk (i.e. variance).
For both formulations `sol$value` will not be the variance `t(wopt)%*%C %*%wopt`. Maybe you have been looking at minimum variance portfolio optimizations? There your variance would be the objective function.

Anyway, you will get the variance of your mean-variance optimization via

```
t(sol$solution)$%*%C%*%sol$solution
```

because `wopt=sol$solution`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think you have answered my question and I have misunderstood the meaning of the output value.

Comment: @Dr_BUG If you think that this is an appropriate answer, you can accept it via clicking on the checkmark.